# Is TLS a "must" requirement in Kubernetes Admission Webhook?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, webhooks, tls1.2

I am trying to setup a custom admission webhook. I do not want TLS protocol for it. I do understand the the client ( which is kube api server) would do an "https" request to the webhook server and hence , we require a TLS Server in Webhook.

The Webhook Server Code is as below. I define a dummy valid cert & key as constants. below server works fine in a the webhook service. :

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "log"

    "net/http"
)

func handleRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello test.. %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
}

type Config struct {
    CertFile string
    KeyFile  string
}

func main() {
    log.Print("Starting server ...2.2")

    http.HandleFunc("/test", handleRoot)

    config := Config{
        CertFile: cert,
        KeyFile:  key,
    }

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":9543",
        TLSConfig: configTLS(config),
    }
    err := server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func configTLS(config Config) *tls.Config {
    sCert, err := tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(config.CertFile), []byte(config.KeyFile))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return &tls.Config{
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{sCert},
        ClientAuth:         tls.NoClientCert,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }
}
```

Also the MutatingWebhookConfiguration yaml looks like below:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    test-webhook-service.io/system: "true"
  name: test-webhook-service-mutating-webhook-configuration
webhooks:
- admissionReviewVersions:
  - v1
  - v1beta1
  clientConfig:
    service:
      name: test-webhook-service-service
      namespace: test-webhook-service-system
      path: /test
  failurePolicy: Ignore
  matchPolicy: Equivalent
  name: mutation.test-webhook-service.io
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - ""
    apiVersions:
    - v1
    operations:
    - CREATE
    - UPDATE
    resources:
    - pods
  sideEffects: None
```

Now, In order to test whether the admission controller works, I created a new POD. The admission controller gives error:

```
2022/09/30 05:42:56 Starting server ...2.2
2022/09/30 05:43:23 http: TLS handshake error from 10.100.0.1:37976: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

What does this mean? Does this mean I have to put valid `caBundle` in the MutatingWebhookConfiguration and thus, TLS is required. If this is the case, I am not sure what following means in the official k8s document ([source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#authenticate-apiservers)):

> The example admission webhook server leaves the ClientAuth field
> empty, which defaults to NoClientCert. This means that the webhook
> server does not authenticate the identity of the clients, supposedly
> API servers.

Comment: I think the API server uses the SSL certificate of the webhook server to authenticate the webhook server. This is a requirement.

The webhook server can also authenticate requests from the API server. This part is optional.